# JDBC SQL Server errors: ClassNotFound & Not Suitable Driver Found

Tags: java, sql-server, database, jdbc, connection

I am very new to Java and am simply trying to connect to my MSSQL database and return a list of customers. When I try the JDBC connection, I get a "no suitable driver found" error. When I add a `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")` statement, I get a ClassNotFound error. This seems like it should be a lot easier than it's turning out to be. Please help me either find a suitable driver or how to get access through the Class.forName usage.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DbConn {

    public static String getConnString(){
        return "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;database=OhHold;";
    }

    public static void getConnection() {
        try
        {
            //Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            String user = "<USER>";
            String pw = "****************";
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(getConnString(), user, pw);
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            String sql = "select txtCompanyName as company from tblCustomers where intNotActive <> 1";
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            while (result.next()) {
                System.out.println(result.getString(1));
            }

        }
        /*
        // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         */
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the driver jar on your classpath? "This seems like it should be a lot easier than it's turning out to be." I don't know why you would assume that. It's very easy when you have plenty of experience, but if you don't have any experience, everything programming related is difficult and requires careful reading of documentation etc.

Comment: That's all it was was a missing JAR from the classpath. Thank you.

I have 20 years experience in Python and C#. I know I shouldn't make assumptions like I did, however with the experience I do have, I felt it should have been quicker. Either way, I thank you for your help.